# Can we compare odds ratio from one factor to another factor?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, importance

For example ${\rm logit}(\pi)=\beta_1 \cdot x_1+ \beta_2 \cdot x_2$, then I find that the odds ratio of $x_2$ is 27, and the odds ratio of $x_1$ is 1.5, can I say that $x_2$ has a more significant effect than $x_1$?

Comment: You can say that $x_2$ has a more effect than $x_1$ when they change by the same units. (given both of them are significant)